# repaired disk/permissions, now imac won't boot into login

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, imac, startup, permission

My iMac has been running horrendously slow the past couple days, so I booted into the Snow Leopard CD and ran a disk repair and a permissions repair.  Now I can't get past the spinner.  It's been going for about 4 hours now with no shows of progress.  Does any body have any ideas on what else I can try (I already tried doing the repairs again) or is there any way I can debug this?

Comment: Have you tried booting in Safe Mode? http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1455

Answer (score 2):

There's a free app called [AppleJack](http://applejack.sourceforge.net/) that's good for ths kind of thing. If you don't have that, [Apple Hardware Test](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) may help.

Comment: +1 AHT.  Hold D while booting your iMac to get into that.

Answer (score 1):

Try Verbose Boot - Command-V while starting, it will show you what the systme is doing as it starts up instead of a pretty gray face.  If you get anything like "disk0s2: I/O Error" you're looking at a failing hard drive.  Go to the nearest [Genius Bar](http://www.apple.com/retail/geniusbar/) or [other AASP](http://www.apple.com/buy/locator/service/).  If you get hung up with some other errors, try re-installing the system from the Snow Leopard DVD.

Answer (score 1):

When you ran a disk verify (which, IIRC,  you must do before you can run a disk repair,) what were the errors that came up?  You may be looking at a dying hard-drive.  Try to use the iMac as little as possible until we (or someone at Apple/with an Apple certification) can help you figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

If it'll boot into single-user mode (hold Cmd-S while booting) try repairing it with fsck (filesystem consistency check and interactive repair) -- "help fsck" when you get the prompt.  Work carefully; you'll have root permissions!

Comment: This is what Disk Utility does. Shouldn't make any difference doing this or using the GUI utility on the install disc.

Comment: Most advice I read concerning fsck suggests that it's a poor idea to run it on a mounted file system because the FS can change underneath it, and that it won't fix any errors in that case.  Thus, my recommendation for running it in single-user mode.  See http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-2666.html , for example; or Google 'fsck multi-user' for others.

Comment: That's why I said 'on the install disc'. That way, you've booted with the CD and the HDD's fs isn't in the way.